# I received a response from the sever I wanted to decode it before I use it further

Tags: ios, swift, decode, encode

I have a string received from the server and I was trying to decode the string with padding but it is throwing nil as result. I tried codes that are available in stack overflow but of no use. Help will be highly appreciated.

I tried with base64 encoded with ignore unknown characters option and padding, still it throws nil.

```
let pem = "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"
```

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: dataStr, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)

  let length = dataStr.count
        dataStr = dataStr.padding(toLength: length + (4 - length % 4) % 4, withPad: "=", startingAt: 0)`
```

It has to give some decoded data with which I can create a certificate because the response is in the format of `.cert`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A certificate is not a string. You cannot create a string from the raw `Data`.

You can decode the base64 encoded string simply with

```
let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: dataStr)
```

Notes:

- Don't use `NSData` in Swift.
- The `ignoreUnknownCharacters` is not needed.
- The padding is wrong. It's only required when **en**coding the data and the base64 related API of `String` and `Data` adds the `=` characters automatically.

Answer (score 0):

May be It will Help 
For Image I am doing like this
I am converting UIImage To data and Converting That data to base64EncodedString

```
let imageData = UIimage.pngData()
//encode string
let imgBase64Str = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters) ?? ""
//decoding string to data
let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: imgBase64Str, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
```